# How to query Apollo GraphQL server with a specific context?

Tags: graphql, apollo

I am writing an Apollo GraphQL API that returns product information from various brands. A simplified version of the schema looks like this:

```
type Query {
  products: [Product]!
}

type Product {
  name: String!
  brand: String!
}
```

I want to be able to query products from a specific brand. Normally this would be simple to achieve by adding a `brand` argument to the `Product` object:

```
type Query {
    products(brand: String!): [Product]!
}
```

However, I have multiple GraphQL clients in different apps and each is associated with a specific brand so it seems redundant to always pass the same `brand` argument in every query. I also have many other objects in my schema (orders, transactions, etc.) that are specific to a brand and would require a `brand` argument.

Furthermore, my resolvers need to query a different API depending on the brand so even objects in my schema such as `User`, which are conceptually unrelated to a brand, would potentially need a `brand` argument so that the resolver knows which API to fetch from.

Is there a way to set the brand context for each client and have this context received by the server? Or maybe there is a better way to achieve this brand separation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably make `Brand` be a first-class type in your GraphQL query.  That doesn't save you from having to qualify many of the queries you describe by a specific brand, but it at least gives you a common place to start from.  Then you'd wind up with an API somewhat like:

```graphql
type Query {
  brand(name: String!): Brand
  allProducts: [Product!]!
}
type Brand {
  name: String!
  products: [Product!]!
  # users: [User!]!
}
type Product {
  name: String!
  brand: Brand! # typical, but not important to your question
}
```

If the differences between kinds of brands are visible at the API layer, you also could consider using a GraphQL [interface](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#interfaces) to describe the set of fields that all brands have, but actually return a more specific type from the resolver.

The way you describe your application, it could also make sense to run one copy of the service for each brand, each with a different GraphQL endpoint.  That would let you straightforwardly parameterize the per-brand internal object configuration and make the "current brand" be process-global context.  The big constraints here are that, at a GraphQL level, one brand's objects can never refer to another, and if you have a lot of brands, you need some good way to run a lot of servers.

Comment: Thanks. For us, a server for each brand would be too much maintenance, even with containerisation. Do you know if it's possible with Apollo to have the same server respond to different endpoints? If so, I could examine the `req` object for the endpoint, which would identify the brand. I have checked the docs but couldn't find any info on this approach.

Comment: I've done a little more research and it is possible to use Apollo within an Express app, which would allow multiple endpoints to be routed to the same Apollo Server. An alternative approach is to have multiple servers within the same app https://glitch.com/edit/#!/terrific-trouser?path=server.js:1:0 which would allow each brand to share objects/context. However, your option of having multiple services has scaling benefits so there's a few pros and cons to weight up. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.